# Live data does not render in morris line graph

Tags: javascript, morris.js

my js looks like as below

```
var lineData =  Morris.Line({
  element: 'morris-line-chart',
  data: [{"Day":"08-11-2015","Ucount":2},{"Day":"09-11-2015","Ucount":23},{"Day":"10-11-2015","Ucount":4},{"Day":"11-11-2015","Ucount":6},{"Day":"12-11-2015","Ucount":3}],
  xkey: 'Day',
  ykeys: ['Ucount'],
  labels: ['Usage Count'],
  parseTime:false
});

      $.ajax({ url: 'http://127.0.0.1:7101/MUDRESTService/rest/v1/mudusagebyday?onlyData=true',             
             type: 'get',  
             dataType: 'json',    
             success: function(output) {
                console.log('line first resp');
                console.log(output) ; 

                var ddata = JSON.stringify(output.items);
                console.log('vik says');
                console.log(ddata);
                lineData.setData(ddata);
             }        
           });
```

if i comment the setData then it works fine. Pleae note that the payload hardcoded in the graph is exact same what my js is trying to set to setData.

i do not see any error in the javascript console. with live data it renders x-axis as undefined.

Comment: Could you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ please ?

Comment: dont how to make that as it has other dependencies. but here is the line part  http://jsfiddle.net/tkbx3bkL/

Answer (score 0):

the problem was morris interpreted the outcome as string so i had to do

```
var arr = JSON.parse(ddata);
chart.setData(arr);
```